# Apt forces me to install Lightdm with Xfce4

Tags: raspbian-stretch, desktop

I am trying to install Xfce4 on my Pi (Raspbian Stretch lite).

When I perfom `sudo apt install xfc4` one of the packages that wants to install is `lightdm`. After checking the dependencies of  Xfce4 with `apt show xfce4`, lightdm is not in the dependencies nor suggested or recommended packages.

Why `apt` wants me to install Lightdm? How can I install Xfce4 without Lightdm?